# error validating data: couldn't find type

Tags: yaml, kubectl

I have following `yaml` file:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: pod
metadata:
    name: Tesing_for_Image_pull.pod 
    spec:
        containers:
        - name: mysql 
          image: mysql 
          imagePullPolicy: Always 
          command: ["echo", "SUCCESS"]
```

When I use `kubectl create -f Tesing_for_Image_pull.yaml` , I get the following error:

```
error: error validating "Tesing_for_Image_pull.yaml": error validating data: couldn't find type: v1.pod; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

kubernetes is picky and case-sensitive:

`kind: Pod`

should do it.

Also, `spec` should not be in `metadata`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: Testing
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mysql
    image: mysql
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    command: ["echo", "SUCCESS"]
```